# Is there build-in cross and dot products in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Is there build-in cross and dot products in CUDA like in opencl, so cuda kernels can use it?
I have nothing found in the specification until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find definitions for these functions in cutil_math.h in the SDK.

There are routines for the dot product in [CuBLAS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUBLAS_Library.pdf).